# ib_insync saving fundamentalRatios in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, stock, interactive-brokers

I am trying to convert or save fundamentalRatios into pandas Dataframe for further ANalysis
My code snippet is here

```
import pandas as pd
from ib_insync import *
from stockstats import StockDataFrame
util.startLoop()
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1',7497, clientId=77)
stk= Stock('TSLA', 'SMART', 'USD')
ticker = ib.reqMktData(stk, '258')
ib.sleep(5)
ticker.fundamentalRatios
```

**OUTPUT**

```
FundamentalRatios(TTMNPMGN=1.86323, NLOW=57.84, ACFSHR=1.558192, ALTCL=nan, TTMPRCFPS=146.5743, 
TTMCFSHR=2.81231, ASFCF=-554, AEPSNORM=-0.83006, TTMRECTURN=19.53421, AATCA=12103, QCSHPS=9.26344, 
TTMFCF=799.4, LATESTADATE='2020-06-30', APTMGNPCT=-2.70567, TTMNIAC=368, EV_Cur=403016.1, 
QATCA=15336, 
PR2TANBK=42.44729, TTMFCFSHR=0.83055, NPRICE=425.79, ASICF=1, REVTRENDGR=50.3571, QSCEX=-566, 
PRICE2BK=40.1811, ALSTD=nan, AOTLO=2405, TTMPAYRAT=0, QPR2REV=65.60383, TTMREVCHG=3.0735, 
TTMROAPCT=1.36842, QTOTCE=9855, APENORM=-492.4842, QLTCL=12270, QSFCF=-45, TTMROIPCT=2.11798, 
DIVGRPCT=nan, QOTLO=964, TTMEPSCHG=110.1973, YIELD=0, TTMREVPS=26.70961, TTMEBT=570, ADIV5YAVG=nan, 
Frac52Wk=0.8335162, NHIG=502.49, ASCEX=-1437, QTA=38135, TTMGROSMGN=19.77206, QTL=28280, AFPRD=798, 
QCURRATIO=1.24988, TTMREV=25708, TTMINVTURN=5.57405, QCASH=8615, QLSTD=0, TTMOPMGN=4.7845, 
TTMPR2REV=3.080634, QSICF=0, TTMNIPEREM=9975.842, EPSCHNGYR=121.7348, TTMPRFCFPS=496.3157, 
TTMPTMGN=2.21721, AREVPS=27.77175, AEBTNORM=-516, ASOPI=-69, NetDebt_I=5524, PRYTDPCTR=376.09721, 
TTMEBITD=3445.851, AFEEPSNTM=2.984, EPSTRENDGR=nan, QTOTD2EQ=143.4703, QSOPI=327, QBVPS=10.59677, 
YLD5YAVG=nan, PR13WKPCT=40.70401, PR52WKPCT=610.4078, AROAPCT=-2.420037, QTOTLTD=9291, 
TTMEPSXCLX=0.38866, QPRCFPS=445.9840754264795, QTANBVPS=10.05054, AROIPCT=-3.826488, QEBIT=327, 
QEBITDA=894, MKTCAP=396754.8, TTMINTCOV=2.11532, TTMROEPCT=4.72692, TTMREVPERE=535404.9, 
AEPSXCLXOR=-0.9740113, QFPRD=111, REVCHNGYR=-4.94003, AFPSS=1285, CURRENCY='USD', 
EV2EBITDA_Cur=450.801, PEEXCLXOR=1095.533, QQUICKRATI=0.92241, ASINN=nan, QFPSS=57, BETA=1.91633, 
ANIACNORM=-765.1497, PR1WKPCT=-5.143913, QLTD2EQ=106.139, QSINN=nan, PR4WKPCT=9.799118, AEBIT=-72)
```

I want to save output i.e Fundamental Ratios in pandas Dataframe

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Save it into a dictionary and process it further like i.e.

```
pd.DataFrame(ticker.fundamentalRatios.__dict__, index=['0'])
```